# Which terms accurately describe the lens mount on a Canon 7?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-mount, old-cameras, rangefinder

I've gotten a used Canon Model 7 rangefinder camera from my grandfather. I'm given to understand that it's a reasonably cool old camera, and the 50mm/1.4 lens isn't too shabby either.

I am considering whether to also get a 35mm lens for this camera, and I'm having a little trouble understanding all the terminology. If I'm correct, the following keywords describe lenses which are compatible with this camera:

- L39 mount
- Leica thread mount or LTM
- Leica screw mount

The following terms describe incompatible lenses:

- Leica M mount

The following I'm not sure about:

- Leica M39 mount

Is a M39-mount lens actually compatible or no? Am I right about the other terms? Am I correct in surmising that basically the only place to find any compatible lens is eBay? :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [instagram.com](http://distilleryimage7.ak.instagram.com/ad10a97477b311e39b0d1291fd40f4c7_8.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"M39" describes Leica's screw mount, and most M39 lenses on the used market are Leica M39 compatible. *Most.* And therein lies the problem.

"M39" only tells you that it's the standard diameter for a metric 39mm screw. That's about as useful as knowing that a bolt is a 1/4" bolt. You also need to know the thread pitch and profile.

A lens that is only specced as "M39" *may* be a 39mm/26tpi Whitworth Leica-mount lens. Or it may be a 24tpi early Canon lens (which won't fit your Canon 7). Or it may be a 39mm x 1 DIN thread screw (mostly Eastern European lenses), which also won't fit the Canon 7 (or a Leica). Or, rather, they'll fit if you force them a bit, since they're *almost* 26tpi (25.4 tpi), which may then keep your other lenses from fitting properly unless you force them a bit too. (Rinse and repeat until there are no threads left on the camera body.)

And it doesn't help that most of the later Soviet lenses *were* Leica mount (to fit the Zenit rangefinder) and that Canon and FED, who were the main non-Leica oddballs in the beginning, went on to become the major Leica-compatible screw mount rangefinder lensmakers. A little research can save a lot of trouble.

And no, eBay isn't your only source. There are still very good used equipment retailers out there, like [KEH](http://www.keh.com/Camera/format-35mm/system-Leica-Screwmount?s=1&bc=39&bcode=LS&bco=525&), that can limit the risks involved in purchasing (especially) the more desirable Cosina Voigtlanders and so on that you might want to consider using on a Micro Four Thirds camera as well as on your rangefinder. And while the prices may not get quite as low as a "really bad for the seller" eBay auction, they're usually better than what you'd get on a "quite good for the seller" auction.